# ISNULL, COALESCE functions

Tags: sql-server

How do I use ISNULL with int values, varchar values

```
 select Complaint.complaintProfileId,ISNULL(T2.MMB_id,'Notfound') as MMBId
from complaints c join T2..
on T2.sno = c.sno
```

This query gives me an error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Notfound' to data type int.
MMB_id is a int
```

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 3):

Try converting your int column to a varchar,

```
SELECT Complaint.ComplaintProfileId, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(11), T2.MMB_id), 'Notfound') AS MMBId
FROM complaints c join T2..
ON T2.sno = c.no
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to return, if you want the text 'Not Found' then you can do the following to your `SELECT` with a `CASE` statement:

```
select Complaint.complaintProfileId,
    CASE
        WHEN T2.MMB_id is not null Then T2.MMB_id
        ELSE 'Not Found'
    END  as MMBId
from complaints c join T2..
on T2.sno = c.sno
```

Since the `MMD_ID` is an `int` you can also do the following to return an `int`:

```
select Complaint.complaintProfileId, IsNull(T2.MMB_id, 0) as MMBId
    from complaints c join T2..
    on T2.sno = c.sno
```

It's up to your based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

```
select Complaint.complaintProfileId,ISNULL(T2.MMB_id,0) as MMBId from complaints c join T2 on T2.sno = c.sno
```

Answer (score 0):

For ISNULL, the first value determines the data type of the expression and the 2nd value is converted to the type of the first expression.  So it is trying to convert your varchar to an int.  I think COALESCE takes the data type with the highest precedence of all the expressions in the COALESCE, which I think in this case would still be the int.  So either way I think you need to cast the int to varchar.